# Credential problems when using both S3 and Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark SQL program, getting data from both S3 and Redshift, joining the data, and writing back out to Redshift on EMR.  I am having a credential issue where that once I query Redshift, I am unable to access EMR any longer, and my program errors with:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).'
```

The code am connecting to redshift with is:

```
df.write \
 .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
 .option("url", rs_jdbc + ":" + rs_port + "/" + rs_db + "?user=" + rs_username + "&password=" + rs_password) \
 .option("dbtable", table) \
 .option("tempdir", s3_temp_out) \
 .mode("error") \
 .save(mode='append')
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the access key and secret key to spark session.
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
  sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET_KEY)

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work setting "fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId" and "fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", feel free to add an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not suggest to use access key and secret key. It is better to use arn of corresponding role as described [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift).

> Have Redshift assume an IAM role (most secure): You can grant Redshift
>   permission to assume an IAM role during COPY or UNLOAD operations and
>   then configure this library to instruct Redshift to use that role:
>
> ```
> Create an IAM role granting appropriate S3 permissions to your bucket.
> Follow the guide Authorizing Amazon Redshift to Access Other AWS Services On Your Behalf to configure this role's trust policy in order
> ```
>
> to allow Redshift to assume this role.
>       Follow the steps in the Authorizing COPY and UNLOAD Operations Using IAM Roles guide to associate that IAM role with your Redshift
>   cluster.
>       Set this library's aws_iam_role option to the role's ARN.